# Why do I cannot access hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am going to add *Book1*'s data to hash *bl*, but when I run code it returns me

> :in `booklist': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

And this is my code.

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author, :language, :classification, :isbn, :book_id, :borrow_status



  def initialize(title, author, language, classification, isbn, book_id, borrow_status)
    @title = title
    @author = author
    @language = language
    @classification = classification
    @isbn = isbn
    @book_id = book_id
    @borrow_status = borrow_status
  end



  def booklist(bl)
     bl = {
    "Title " => @title.title.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" "),
    "Author " => @author.title.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" "),
    "Language " => (@language.title),
    "Classification " => @classification,
    "ISBN " => @isbn.to_s,
    "Book ID" => @book_id.to_s,
    "Status" => @borrow_status
    }
    end


  def put_booklist
    booklist.each do |x , y|
      puts "#{x}" , "#{y}"
    end
  end


end

books1 = Book.new("lonely planet: ireland","damian harper","english","tourism",9781786574459,1,"available")
books1.put_booklist
```

I would like to know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `booklist` method expects a parameter, but in this call you're passing none

```
booklist.each do |x , y|
```

Anyway, it turns out by the definition for `booklist` you don't need nor use that parameter. Move `booklist` to

```
def booklist
  {
    "Title " => @title.title.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" "),
    "Author " => @author.title.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" "),
    "Language " => (@language.title),
    "Classification " => @classification,
    "ISBN " => @isbn.to_s,
    "Book ID" => @book_id.to_s,
    "Status" => @borrow_status
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use your method, but it return me **: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)**, I am still feel confusing.

Comment: You should just get rid of the parameter in the `booklist` definition

Comment: My pleasure sir :)